# How can I save a plot with closed boxed area in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, save, line

How can I close the plot area with black lines in the top and right side when I save a plot?

I don't have any idea how to make it or how to search, if anyone knows please tell me.

For example look at the plot shown below, where the lines are missing:

[image: blah]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you save your image, use the [`box`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/box.html) command.  This will enclose your plot to have the surrounding black box as you have specified in your example image.  Simply call:

```
box on;
```

To turn it off, do:

```
box off;
```

Example:

```
%// Plot a line from 1 to 5 for x and y
x = 1:5;
y = 1:5;
plot(x,y);
box on;
```

This is what the plot looks like:

[image]

If you were to turn boxing **off**, this is what the plot looks like:

[image]

`box off;` is the default behaviour for `plot`, as you have seen in the example image you have shown.  Simply call `box on;` after the plot is shown and before you save your image to get the desired effect.

Comment: @user3683409 - You're very welcome :) Please consider accepting my answer if this has helped you!

Comment: I will, im just waiting four minutes! (rules) ;)

Comment: @user3683409 - Ahahaha I must have answered too quickly.  Thank you :)  I didn't know there was a time limit for accepting another answer.  Oops!